# Update table1 from table2 value by recent date

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I wanted to update table1 based on table2 which has a common field employee_ID. I always have unique employee_ID in table1 but in table2 it may contain duplicate records with same employee_ID.

I got another column in table2 where the modified_date is inserted. I want to update the table1 employee name with the table2 employee name based on employee_id and recent modified date.

I got multiple columns to update with the same type of condition. any idea, here is so far i tried.

[image]

Here is the query, i have using inner join,

```
ssql = "Update Table1 INNER JOIN Table2 
ON Table1.employee_id= Table2.employee_id 
SET Table1.type= Table2.type"
```

any help will be appreciated

Comment: And what is the issue with your query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this query

```
update t1 set t1.employee_name = t2.employee_name from table1 as t1
inner join table2 as t2 on t1.employee_id = t2.employee_id
where t2.Modified_date = (select Max(modified_date) from table2 as tb2 where 
tb2.employee_id = t2.employee_id group by tb2.employee_id)
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your reply. The modified date is not known here. It has to take the recent date record from the available records with that same employee id. For example if dates are like 01-jan-2017 and 01-jan-2018 then it has to pick the 01-jan-2018 record.

Comment: I tried Vivek's  Solution. It was working fine. I yet to try Indent answer. Anyway thanks a lot!!!

Answer (score 1):

You need an intermediate step to associate the Max(modified_date) to each employee_id.

Using a [CTE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/queries-with.html) expression you can try something like this :

```
with
more_recent as (
    select
        employee_id,
        Max(modified_date) max_modified_date
    from
        table2
    group by
        employee_id    
)
update
    t1
set
    t1.employee_name = t2.employee_name
from
    table1 as t1
    inner join more_recent mr on 
        t1.employee_id = mr.employee_id
    inner join table2 as t2 on 
        mr.employee_id = t2.employee_id
        mr.max_modified_date = t2.modified_date
```

Comment: Hi, the query listed here is working fine for one date column. How do i change a query to sort and have latest records in two date columns and pick the record